# I want to hear opinions about the chain: VPN1==>TOR==>VPN2==>TOR (using Kodachi Linux with USB + Kodachi Linux with Virtualbox)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, linux, vpn

I would like to hear your opinion about this connection chain, what can you say anonymously and whether it is secure.

1. Boot Linux Kodachi in Live mode from USB
2. Turn on a reliable VPN1
3. After that I Torify the whole system.
4. Launch VirtualBox and emulate another Linux Kodachi in Live mode.
5. Launch VPN2
6. After that I will torify the whole system.

In total, I get this connection:

```
(Linux Kodachi from USB) VPN1 ==> TOR => (VirtualBox Linux Kodachi) VPN2 ==> TOR ==> TOR DNS
```

- Speed ​​suits me

Do you think it is anonymous?

Is the `vpn => tor => vpn => tor` chain anonymous?

Or maybe just `vpn => tor => .....`?

What problems could there be, сonsidering virtualbox has no shared folders, clipboard,etc. with the host machine?

**Perhaps you know more interesting and reliable ways to set up such a connection chain. Thanks to all!**

PART II

- I understand that using `tor => vpn` is a bad idea, I use `vpn => tor`, but I want to add a virtual machine to this bundle using all the features of Linux Kodachi.
- Based on what you wrote, I understand that there is no point in the `vpn-tor-vpn-tor` bundle? Or is it still interesting?
- Do you think this option is interesting? (`Kodachi from usb) vpn1 => (kodachi from vurtualbox) => vpn => tor`?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty bulletproof, but the second VPN is redundant and might even harm your privacy as it would allow the operators of VPN2 to see your traffic just like VPN1. In that way, Tor would not provide much protection.

An easier and more feasible solution in terms of speed would be to use hardened Whonix over a (not necessarily trustworthy) VPN. Even though it may harm your privacy to use a VPN over Tor, if you do any risky activities (accidentally, which is more common than you think), such as torrenting or running certain malicious or poorly configured web features, your real IP would be exposed. See proof: https://blog.torproject.org/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea Leaking a VPN IP address provides at least some infinitesimal benefit over leaking your real IP.

All in all, just use common sense and choose your battles wisely.

Comment: First of all, thanks you for your answer.

I add questions  in my post, check please

Comment: If you use a VPN and tor on top of Kodachi Linux, you run the risk of exposing yourself. For example, signing up for VPNs and the complexity of virtual machines will probably make more noise than you would like to attract. Inevitably, you will mess up at some point. A more complex machine is worse than a simple machine.

Answer (score 0):

You've quadrupled your attack surface, and the only benefit is to make things slightly harder for someone trying to follow the connection chain backwards.  But that's already the hardest way to compromise your identity.  Any sensible attacker is going to go at it from the side: compromising VPNs, monitoring TOR exit nodes, or trying to get you to run software that reveals your identity.  Your complicated system just gives a sensible attacker more things to target.